# Delete specific files on all remote computers joined to the domain

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I need to add something to first run as admin and second to run on all computers on the domain.

```
forfiles -p "C:\ProgramData\ESET\ESET Endpoint Antivirus\Logs\eScan" -s -m *.dat /D -0 /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

Comment: Btw. this question belongs on Super User as it's more about client administration than scripting/progamming.

Answer (score 1):

Add it in a startup script or as a scheduled task by using Group Policy or use a system management solution like System Center Configuration Manager (SCCM) if you have it available.

Avoid script-solutions like PowerShell, VbScript, `psexec` etc. to run this on the computers because you would need to run them x times to reach every computer that might have been offline/unavailable the first time. The solutions above are far better at making sure every computer runs it as soon as possible.